# R: LOOCV warnings

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm doing LOOCV with multiple linear regression. I get some warnings after I run the code, which I don't understand why I get them.

Here is the code:

```
library(DAAG)
n=30
p=15
real_p=15
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
y=as.matrix(apply(x[, 1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n))
X=as.data.frame(x)
mod=lm(y~., data=X)
cv.lm(mod,data=X, m=n)
```

Here are the warnings:

```
  1: In cv.lm(mod, data = X, m = n) : 

 As there is >1 explanatory variable, cross-validation
 predicted values for a fold are not a linear function
 of corresponding overall predicted values.  Lines that
 are shown for the different folds are approximate

2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '30'
3: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '26'
4: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '27'
5: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '31'
6: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '28'
7: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : unimplemented pch value '29'
```

Comment: You have fewer rows than columns, which is a problem. If you think of it as a system of equations, you need at least one equation for each variable for which you are trying to solve, so in this case at least 20 rows, or with LOOCV, 21, since one will be left out. Alternatively, drop some predictors.

Comment: @alistaire I did that, but I still get some warnings, I will edit my question with the new warnings